# gcc errors for optimization flags (fast=2, -ipo, and -fp-model) when compiling on HPC

Tags: gcc, makefile, gnu, hpc

I am trying to run GIZMO ([http://www.tapir.caltech.edu/~phopkins/Site/GIZMO_files/gizmo_documentation.html#tutorial-running](http://www.tapir.caltech.edu/%7Ephopkins/Site/GIZMO_files/gizmo_documentation.html#tutorial-running)) on my university's HPC of Intel Cascade Lake CPUs. I have been able to compile and run on my own macbook easy enough. I am getting gcc errors despite gnu8 module being loaded.

I have tried switching gnu8 for gcc/11.2.0 but this disables fftw and mpich modules and still gives the same errors. I am new to HPC but understood that -ipo is a pretty standard flag to call for optimization. My makefile:

```
ifeq ($(SYSTYPE),"HPC")
CC       =  mpicc
CXX      =  mpic++
FC       =  $(CC)
OPTIMIZE = -O1 -xhost -ipo  -funroll-loops -fp-model -fast=2
OPTIMIZE += -g -Wall # compiler warnings
#OPTIMIZE += -parallel -openmp  # openmp (comment out this line if OPENMP not used)
ifeq (OPENMP,$(findstring OPENMP,$(CONFIGVARS)))
OPTIMIZE += -parallel -openmp  # openmp required compiler flags
endif
GMP_INCL = #
GMP_LIBS = #
MKL_INCL = #
MKL_LIBS = #
##MKL_LIBS = -L$(TACC_MKL_LIB) -lm -lmkl_core -lmkl_sequential -lmkl_scalapack_lp64 -lmkl_intel_lp64 -lmkl_blacs_intelmpi_lp64
GSL_INCL = -I/work/uij207/gsl/include
GSL_LIBS = -L/work/uij207/gsl/lib
FFTW_INCL= -I/work/uij207/fftw/include
FFTW_LIBS= -L/work/uij207/fftw/lib
HDF5INCL = -I/work/uij207/hdf5/include -DH5_USE_16_API
HDF5LIB  = -L/work/uij207/hdf5/lib -lhdf5 -lz
MPICHLIB = #
OPT     += -DUSE_MPI_IN_PLACE
## modules to load:
## module load intel mvapich2 gsl hdf5 fftw2
##  -- performance is very similar with impi (intel-mpi) instead of mpavich2,
##   if preferred use that with MPICHLIB line uncommented
## newest version of code needed for compatibility with calls in MPI-2 libraries
##
endif
```

Output when running make:

```
mpicc -O2 -xhost -ipo  -funroll-loops -fp-model -fast=2 -g -Wall  -DBUILDINFO='"Build on login002 by uij207 from master:c12bd8a at https://bitbucket.org/phopkins/gizmo-public.git"' -DUSE_MPI_IN_PLACE -I/work/uij207/gsl/include -I/work/uij207/fftw/include -I/work/uij207/hdf5/include -DH5_USE_16_API      -c -o main.o main.c
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-ipo’
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fp-model’
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fast=2’; did you mean ‘-Ofast’?
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear from the error message that is printed by the compiler: `fast=2: no such file or directory`.  The compiler thinks you want to compile a file named `fast=2` because it's not an option: if you want to specify an _option_ you need to prefix it with a dash.  So, `-fast=2`  I'm not familiar with ICC so I have no idea if that's a valid compiler option, but definitely `fast=2` with no `-` prefix is _not_ a valid compiler option.

Comment: Yup, was going too quick to recreate the error to paste here. Corrected with the '-' gives the same error for unrecognized command line option as with the other flags

Comment: Well, you have to look at the documentation for the underlying compiler to find out what options are available.  Options that aren't available, won't work.

Comment: `-ipo` is not at all a standard optimization flag for GCC.  It may be supported by some other compilers, but as far as I can tell, it is not meaningful to any version of GCC between 4 and 12.  Not even as an arch-specific option. Same with `-fast` / `-fast=2`, though there is `-Ofast` (which does not accept an argument).  There are several arch-specific `-mfp-*` options, but none look like a good match for `-fp-model`.  I don't know where you got the idea to use these flags, or where they might be appropriate, but they seem wrong for the machine you're building for now.

Comment: @JohnBollinger So taking a step back then, is there a way to find the appropriate flags for this machine if they are not in the machine specific documentation? The machine, afik, was set up with the assumption that any code will be able to self-determine optimization flags and the code I'm using assumes I know the optional flags and have to set them myself.

Comment: @NotSoSN, there is a limited degree of consistency across Unix-style compilers with respect to optimization options, but going beyond that generally requires knowledge of the compiler and benefits from an understanding of the implementation of the software being built.  If you don't have both, nor guidance on the topic, then the safest bet is probably to compile with `-O2` and call it a day.  The result may not be the absolute fastest possible, but you generally won't be leaving much on the table.